# What is a strong API?

Tags: api

I have received this question in a job interview lately. My answer was:

"I believe a strong API is a intuituve, consistent, secure and well documentated one."

It is OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think that's a very reasonable answer.

I might have also added "functioning correctly" and "meeting all agreed-upon requirements," but it seems like that's implicit in your answer.